# Access/Create/Write into several SQLite tables (generic SQLiteHelper)

Tags: c#, android, sqlite, generics, xamarin

I´m currently reestructuring my Xamarin application in order to keep some data into the device.

I´ve already created my tables (14), the connection class and now I´m having some trouble with the DataAccess (Helper) class. I had to make it generic, since its 14 tables we´re talking about, and all the CRUD operations seems to work fine.

But the "GetById" and "List" methods are not working, because it says that the generic type "T" I´m passing must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter:

```
    public class DataAccessSQLite<T> : IDisposable{

    public SQLiteConnection connection;

    public DataAccessSQLite()
    {
        var config = DependencyService.Get<ISQLConfig>();
        connection = new SQLiteConnection(config.Platform, config.Database);
        connection.CreateTable<T>();
    }

    public void Insert(T model)
    {
        connection.Insert(model);
    }

    public void Delete(T model)
    {
        connection.Delete(model);
    }

    public void Update(T model)
    {
        connection.Update(model);
    }

    public T GetbyId(int id)
    {
        //HERE IS THE ERROR:
        return connection.Table<T>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
    }

    public List<T> ToList()
    { 
        //ALSO HERE
        return connection.Table<T>().OrderBy().ToList();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        connection.Dispose();
    }
}
```

I was thinking on implementing a singleton aproach to access all the tables but not sure how I would do that.

I know that the generic aproach (T) I´m using now wouldn´t work anyways for the GetById cause there is no way he could know what Id to get by just passing the "T". So what I actually need is to do it some other way.

How can I make this class generic in order to access all the tables through it?

ERROR I´M GETTING: **The type 'T' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'SQLiteConnection.Table()'**

---

UPDATE:

Using **where T : class** resolves the error I was getting, but I´m still unable to get the Id from the tables by just passing "T"

Answer (score 0):

By reading your error, you should try this:

```
public class DataAccessSQLite<T> : IDisposable
    where T : class
```

`where T : class` is a generic constraint that specifies that `T` is a reference type and it can't be a value type.

Comment: This resolves the error I was getting, but I´m still unable to get the Id of the tables:

_'T' does not contain a definition for 'Id' and no extension method 'Id' accepting a first argument of type 'T' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)_

Comment: Do your table classes has the same base class/interface ? Preferably with an `Id` property.